# Python instantly closes when using for loop in selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web, webautomation

I'm trying to create a project witch will fill out an attendance form automatically. I've learned how to use selenium today so the code looks atrocious. My problem is that I'm trying to submit multiple responses in order to fill out all 5 of my periods. So I am using a for loop to put in the correct period for each of the 5 responses. My problem is that it seems that any code that is indented farther than the first indentation just closes python as soon as it opens.

```
for i in range(0,5):
if i == 0:
    formPeriodTwo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/span')
    formPeriodTwo.click()
    time.sleep(1)
elif i == 1:
    formPeriodTwo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[5]/span')
    formPeriodTwo.click()
    time.sleep(1)
elif i == 2:
    formPeriodTwo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[7]/span')
    formPeriodTwo.click()
    time.sleep(1)
elif i = 3:
    formPeriodTwo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[8]/span')
    formPeriodTwo.click()
    time.sleep(1)
elif i = 4:
    formPeriodTwo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[9]/span')
    formPeriodTwo.click()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I'm simply pressing a different option from the drop down menu based on what "i" is.
This also happened when I tried to use an if statement earlier, but I was able to work around the if statement. Could if statements be the issue?
if I comment out the four loop the python opens and does its job. But if the for loop is in, the python instantly closes. What could cause this? Does selenium stop for loops? Am I using the for loop wrong?

After some more testing I have found that
this works and can be called as a function later

```
def printTest():
print("hello")
```

as well as this

```
def printTest():
print("hello")
for i in range(0,4):
    print("world")
```

Which means that something about that specific for loop is messing up python

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you correct your indentation to ensure that it matches your actual code, and run your code using the `python` command in the command line so that the prompt will stay open so you can get an error. I'm assuming you're currently running it by double clicking on the script?

Answer (score 0):

your indentation is not right, this is how you're suppose to write it.

```
for i in range(0,5):
    elif i == 1:
       formPeriodTwo = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[5]/span')
       formPeriodTwo.click()
       time.sleep(1)
```

this is how the indentation should be change it for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

To simply loop and get the xpath corresponding to the i index.

```
lst=[4,5,7,8,9]
for i in lst:
    try:
        formPeriod= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[{}]/span'.format(i))
        formPeriod.click()
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        print('Invalid')
```